# laravel excel export adding additional header row

Tags: php, excel, laravel-excel

here is my code:

```
   Excel::create($file_name, function ($excel) use ($data, $sheet_name) {
        $excel->sheet($sheet_name, function ($sheet) use ($data) {


            $data[] = ['id', 'customer', 'email', 'total', 'created_at'];
            $data[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
            $data[] = ['11', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
            $data[] = ['111', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
            $data[] = ['1111', '2', '3', '4', '5'];


            $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', true, true);
            });

        // Set the title
         $excel->setTitle('Our new awesome title');
        // Chain the setters
        $excel->setCreator('test')->setCompany('test');

        // Call them separately
        $excel->setDescription('A demonstration to change the file properties');

    })->export($type);
```

And this is my output

[image]

why it is adding 0,1,2,3,4 at the top row ?

please help thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
 $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', true, true);
```

it should be this

`$sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);`